# Can't connect to shared folder on the network because the "original item can't be found"

Tags: macos, network

I am running OS X 10.9.5. I have been using a shared hard drive on a home network for over two years.  Recently, one of the folders started giving me the following error when I try to connect to it:

> The operation can’t be completed because the original item for “foldername” can’t be found.

I don't recall changing any permissions or anything.  Other folders on the same drive work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Apple HFS filesystem tracks files according to a (hopefully) unique identifier instead of a path when it can.

The fastest way forward is to forget the old location / clear the recent history / and navigate to the shared folder and reconnect.

If you can't clear up the history, please post a screen shot of where you are seeing the "old" mount point and perhaps we can guide you there once more detail is provided. In the absence of detail, this general procedure is offered in hopes it helps you resolve things.

Comment: Could you explain how to "forget the old location / clear the recent history /..."?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @oakhill78 sure. How do you connect in the first place? You might need to ask that as a follow on question - post a screen shot or precisely what steps you take to find the old folder....

Comment: This problem occurs, for me, when I mount something in finder.  (command-K, smb://server, etc.)  After the computer sleeps and wakes up, it can't find the old share, but also won't release the share name (it's greyed out) it when reconnecting to the server.

Comment: Well, this has been helpful.